# Got error of the multiplication table in visual basic, can anyone help to correct please?

Tags: vba

```
lblTable.Text = ""    
For i = 1 To 4
    For j = 1 To 4
        lblTable.Text = i & "×" & j & "=" & i * j
    Next j
Next i
```

As the code shows above, I tried to make multiplication table from 1 to 4, but when I ran the program, the table would all show in one row, not like the sample. Is there anything miss in my code?
[image: Here is the sample program that I tried to do as]

Comment: You are just adding on to one big string.  You need some formatting in there (like tab characters), at a minimum. Better would be individual controls, one per calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how you're getting that "table" to display in the form (you must have omitted the code, because the code you provide simply replaces `lblTable.Text` in the inner loop each time.  In any case, you can write each out to an array, and the drop the array to the worksheet like so:

```
Dim arr(1 to 4, 1 to 4) as String
lblTable.Text = ""    
For i = 1 To 4
    For j = 1 To 4
        lblTable.Text = i & "×" & j & "=" & i * j
        arr(i,j) = lblTable.Text
    Next j
Next i
Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
```

Answer (score 0):

Format your label with a non-proportional font so everything lines up.

```
Dim s as string, i, j

s = ""    
For i = 1 To 4
    For j = 1 To 4
        s = s & Left(i & "×" & j & "=" & (i * j) & "       ", 9)
        if j = 4 Then s = s & chr(10)
    Next j
Next i
lblTable.Text = s
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But onle the last 4x4=16 looks like one more space.